# fit text inside uiwebview

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uiwebview

Hi I'm displaying a multiline text inside a uiwebview. I'm using this instead of uitextview coz Im displaying some fancy symbols like degrees, superscript, subscripts, etc. My question is how can I fit all the text inside a fixed width and height of the uiwebview. Say, I have a uiwebview of 300x200 I want all the text to fit inside that view. see the image below to see my problem.
http://i228.photobucket.com/albums/ee262/romano2717/photo.png

Answer (score 0):

To resize the height & width try this -

```
webView.autoresizingMask    = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
self.webView.autoresizesSubviews = YES;

//Incase the above does not work.
NSString *jsCommand = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"document.body.style.zoom = 0.5;"];
[self.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:jsCommand];
```

Hope this helps...

Comment: both doesn't work. when I tried using either of those two, the string is clipped upto "The square has a length of 2cm".

Comment: @Diffy you need to add the 2nd set of statements inside webViewDidFinishLoading delegate method of the webview

Answer (score 0):

Set `webView.scalesPageToFit` to YES.

Comment: when I do that it makes the text very small and impossible to read.